# How to ensure only one jQuery is included in grails 3.x

Tags: jquery, grails, grails-3.0

I have a Grails 3 project with some plugins, which all depend on jQuery. All of them serve their own jQuery and one extends it with jQuery plugins. My layout also includes a jQuery.

The assets plugin renders a `<script`-Tag for every plugin requiring jQuery and the template. Thus it overwrites the jQuery plugins from the one grails plugin registering them.

How can I ensure that at most one jQuery file is served?

(BTW: This was no issue in Grails 2. I suspect because jQuery was served from the jQuery grails plugin then, which was commonly included via `//=require jquery` and therefore only one javascript file existed. Now there are many. Am I correct?)

Comment: JQuery from the plugins can be excluded with [a configuration](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks, this does offer the workaround of including jquery once at the top and excluding all jquery by plugins. It's not a very generic solution, though.